# Applescript Sdef: How to define assignable commands?

Tags: applescript, sdef

In my scriptable Mac app, I like to make the following syntax possible:

```
set preference with key <a key> to <a value>
```

Is that possible? How would I specify this in the Sdef?

The only way I can so far come up with is to define a command with the name `set preference with key`, but Apple's [Scripting Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html) says that one should not begin a command with a reserved name such as `set` is here. Is there any other way? Or is it safe to use my idea in this case?

Currently, I avoid this by instead using this, but I don't like that syntax as much as I'd like the more common "set" terminology:

```
write preference with key <a key> value <a value>
```

Better suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Create a class for your preferences using an `AppleScript Object Model`. Then create read/write properties for it.

Comment: @djbazziewazzie You're right. I could do that, and that's probably the cleanest solution. I rather avoid the work that's required for that right now, though, and take the above shortcut. I don't expect more than a handful of people in the world to use this anyway, so this is mainly educational for me :)

Comment: @djbazziewazzie is right.  Take the time, do it correctly.

Comment: I have to agree with dj and Mark. A simple UserPreferences class with some properties, a few entries in the SDEF, and you're done. Additionally, the terminology using key/value in the question strikes me as thinking like a cocoa programmer, instead of like a AS scripter. I'd much prefer terminology such as `set nickname of user preferences to "bubba"` and `properties of user preferences`